# convert ViewBag to routeValues

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In controller I have:

```
ViewBag.SomeObject = "IntVal=5&StrVal=Hello";
```

In view I have:

```
@Html.ActionLink("a", "b", "c", new { page = 5, ViewBag.SomeObject }, null)
```

It gives me link:

```
/c/b?page=5&SomeObject=&IntVal=5&StrVal=Hello
```

But I don't want **SomeObject=&** in url so correct link should look:

```
/c/b?page=5&IntVal=5&StrVal=Hello
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Did you try explicitly casting the `ViewBag` to `string`? Like so `(string)ViewBag.SomeObject`

Comment: Yes but then I have error "Invalid anonymous type member declarator"

Comment: Because Razor unable to deduce parameter name, had you put something like `param = (string)ViewBag.SomeObject` it should compile. But then it won't be what you expected. I suggest you put IntVal and StrVal in separate ViewBag. Something like `IntVal = (string)ViewBag.IntVal` etc..

Comment: I can't do that because this view must be universal, it will be used in many actions in which I will pass many different parameters in ViewBag.SomeObject

Comment: I tested my code today and realised I was calling the wrong method overload. I have fixed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass `RouteValueDictionary` directly into the `ViewBag`. Like so...

```
@Html.ActionLink("LinkText", "ActionName", new RouteValueDictionary(ViewBag.RouteValues))
```

Then in your `Controller` you will have...

```
ViewBag.RouteValues = new RouteValueDictionary( new { 
        Page = 5,
        IntVal = 5,
        StrVal = "Hello"
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In the controller I used...

```
 ViewBag.RouteValues = new { 
        Page = 5,
        IntVal = 5,
        StrVal = "Hello"
    };
```

and in the view...

```
@Html.ActionLink("LinkText", "ActionName", ViewBag.RouteValues as object)
```

and it worked for me.